# SQL Server column design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I always tried to make my sql database as simple and as understandable as possible. 
Until now I always used a limited number of columns, I think I never had more than 20. Now, there is one thing, that would make my life easier, if I had much more columns. Let´s say 200 columns. (not rows). What do you think about it?

I just want to know, if it is a bad idea, not why i´m doing this or if there are other possibilities, just if somebody has already experienced something like that and if it is a bad idea to do such a table.

Comment: Could you give some more context on why you need so many columns?

Comment: are you using more than 100 columns in a sqltable? I have a feeling that you didn´t read my text above...

Comment: If you have more than 30, you're most likely doing it wrong, or you've picked up a shitty legacy project to work on.

Comment: @Luke - We need context to give any sort of opinion really. Are you violating 1NF for example? SQL Server 2008 does have sparse columns which may be relevant (or not) dependant upon context. Will your columns have many `NULL` s?

Comment: ok @phill, no i have not more than 30, i just want to know, if there is any problem with it and why

Comment: @Martin no I´m not violating 1NF, @Martin yes, many nulls.

Comment: Why? Because it's not maintainable. It has the chance of going over 8k row size, columns such as VARCHAR() will spill over into their own page, killing performance, and I can't think of any reason you would ever have more than 30 columns, even 30 columns is pushing it.

Comment: ok thanks @phill, thats what i needed to know and what i already believed to know, i just wanted to have it comfirmed.

Comment: @Luke - [Sparse columns](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-Sparse-Columns.aspx) could be quite a good fit for you potentially if you desire many columns with most of them `NULL`. I've never felt the urge to use them myself but I guess they must have some legitimate use cases!

Answer (score 2):

Fewer, smaller width columns is better than lots of columns and/or large width columns.

Why? Because the narrower the row size, the more rows you fit on a 8K page. That means you do less I/O and use less memory to buffer pages. That is always a good thing.

In those (hopefully) rare cases, where the domain requires many attributes on an object (with the assumption of 1-1 object-table mapping), you should consider splitting into two tables ina  1-1 relationship, one containing the frequently used columns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is black and white. Having a large row size (implied by the large number of columns) will hurt performance (i.e., more I/O) -- but there are cases where taking a small hit in performance in one place will be offset by increased performance in others.

I'd say it depends on how many rows you expect this table to have, how often will it will be queried, how many of those additional columns will really be accessed, and how it would compare to your alternative design in terms of efficiency and complexity.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Let´s say, that there will be, well, a huge amount of rows. But mostly only 3 columns will be accessed, and mostly, let me count, a maximum number of 20 rows, filtered by id. But the access is frequent, the data got out of it quite small

Comment: @Luke - Mostly the same 3 columns or a variable 3 columns?

Comment: it would base upon linq to sql inheritance model, so no, of course not the same 3 columns, for just 3 columns i don´t create a table with 200 columns ;-)

Comment: I'd consider creating multiple tables with the best logical grouping you can put together, then join them in a view and use the view with your LINQ. Then profile the queries that get generated and see how efficient it works out to be.

Answer (score 1):

Luke--

It really depends on the type of the system you are working with. Example in transactional systems, most tables have at most 50 columns or so with almost no redundant data attrributes ( If you have a process date, you would not need the Process Month or the process year as a seperate column). This of course is because the records are updated/inserted frequently and you'll need to update all the redundant attributes everytime you update one row.

In Data Warehouse/reporting environments, for Dimension tables (which have the attributes for an entity) it is typical to have 100+ columns as there are could be various ways you want to categorize a given entity.The Updates here are not so much a problem as data is typically loaded once during off-peak hours and then is used mostly in selects.

Take a look at these links to know more..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

So the answer is it depends... If you want a perfectly relational system, then may be 200+ columns is kind of a red flag indicating you should look at normalize your data (May be not). Updates and Indexes are two things that you should be concerned with in such a system.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL Server, which I think defaults to row-oriented storage (all fields in a row are stored together in a page), which can be a problem with large number of columns.  However, if you use column-oriented storage, the number of columns per table does not matter because each column is stored together. I don't know if this is possible with SQL Server.